# Lando recipe don't create php.ini file

Tags: lando

lando.yml create a folder instead a file php.ini in wordpress recipe

This is my code:

```
name: projName
recipe: wordpress

config:
  php: "8.0"
  webroot: .
  via: nginx
  xdebug: true
  config:
    php: config/php.ini
```

it returns a php.ini directory instead php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

you need to add it under the following location:

```
services:
  appserver:
    config:
      php: location/to/php.ini
```